# Swarm mode rolling updates progress

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a full infrastructure with Docker swarm multiple nodes and horizontal scalability.

I use `docker service update` to deploy new version of my application without interruption.

I'm now working on a chatbot to deploy my application from Slack, is there a way to follow the progress of the update? I didn't see any events or webhooks to manage that

It is very scary to launch service update without any info / output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In docker 17.05, a new option `--detach, -d` is introduced to docker service create and update.

There isn't much documentation yet, as usual. You can check the [pull](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/31144). And there is a slightly out of date [demo](https://asciinema.org/a/9f9rgk0e7fczkxi5vfu7yofmw).

This is what I got on 17.05.

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Fri May  5 15:36:11 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Fri May  5 15:36:11 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true

$ docker service create --detach=false --name top --replicas 3 busybox top
804oco5lhezi2estr04ybbn2h
overall progress: 3 out of 3 tasks
1/3: running
2/3: running
3/3: running
verify: Waiting 1 seconds to verify that tasks are stable...

$ docker service update --detach=false --replicas 5 top
top
overall progress: 5 out of 5 tasks
1/5: running
2/5: running
3/5: running
4/5: running
5/5: running
verify: Waiting 1 seconds to verify that tasks are stable...
```